# QT Tools Tab is missing in VS 2019

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2019

I had been using VS2013 for some time and a Qt Tools tab was present (as shown in the screenshot below) after installing ***Qt Visual Studio Tools***

[image]

**PROBLEM:** Now I have installed VS 2019 Community edition. I have already installed ***Qt Visual Studio Tools*** extension. But still, the Qt tab is missing in the ribbon (as shown in the screenshot below). Due to this, I am also not able to set the path of the Qt exe correctly.

**PS:** Qt extension is definitely installed properly because when I try to create a new project, it shows the various options to create Qt project.

[image]

Comment: Could this be related to Qt still not supporting VS2019 ? I remember I tried a Qt Kit for VS 2019 and not available .. though tools 2019 is published ?

Comment: @MohammadAKanan: Don't think so. I installed the Qt extension from the VS2019's extension manager itself. While creating a new project, I am provided with options of Qt project's template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2019 the`Qt VS Tools` menu is a sub-menu in the `Extensions` menu.

Note: the binaries created with VS2013 are not compatible with VS2019, for it to work you need Qt build with Visual Studio 2015 or 2017.